# How to get a certain value from an associative table in sql

Tags: sql, select, associative

I have two tables and one table that associates these two.
Table A has two columns (pk,name)
Table B also has two columns (id,name)
Table AB has three columns (pk(FK of A), id(FK of B), date)

How can I write a select to retrieve A.name, B.name and AB.date
for a certain A.pk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select A.name, B.name, AB.date
from A
join AB on A.pk=AB.pk
join B on AB.id=B.id
where A.pk=value
```